# How can I "revoke and request" my iOS Developer Profile?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to export an `.ipa` file from XCode 6, and I get an error like this:

[image]

The dialog says "revoke the current certificate and request one again", but I don't see a way to do that. [The Apple Troubleshooting page for this issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html) suggests I should click the "Revoke and Request" button, but I don't see one.

How do I revoke the old developer certificate and request a new one?

Comment: You can via iOS developer account, edit and sign your distribution provisioning profile with valid distribution certificate or create new. Please refer to following doc, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the certificate is a distribution one, not development one. It seems that you have installed your iOS Distribution certificate in another Mac. And, it seems again that you download this certificate from Apple portail and import to your new machine. Of course, the simple import is not valid. Cause a certificate requires a private key to be associated with.

Then, you have 2 solutions:

1. Export your certificate from old machine (include private key) then import to your new machine. I recommend it.

[image]

2. Revoke this certificate if you do not use anymore on old machine. Then, from new machine, create new request signning and request again the distribution certificate.
   Visite your account, in distribution certificate section, click to the certificate to revoke, you will see "Revoke" button.

**Beware that all provisioning profiles created with this certificate will be invalidated.**

[image]

Just for info, you have only <= 2 distribution certificates to be created.